# Broker Database failover using default JDBC

Tags: 2011, broker

For months we have been facing issues with our load balancing technique for the Broker DB having a primary and secondary database server.

Recently we got to know from SDL that we can use the old default JDBC connection which would allow us to give primary and secondary DB server names. My question is, did anyone try this, and does it work for a failover situation?

Comment: Which database server are you using?

Comment: we are using SQL

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you considered using a `Redundancy of data` for instance SQL Server Database Cluster or Oracle RAC?

SQL Cluster or Oracle RAC will keep your data redundant and in sync for possible failures. Now  I have noticed in previous projects that an Active / Active configuration is not supported by Tridion and we had to move to an Active / Passive model.